# Configure FBO with depth buffer that has 32 bits

Tags: opengl

I am trying to configure a Frame buffer object with depth buffer that has 32 bits, render to that and then merely copy the resulting color buffer to the system color buffer.

Can someone help me how to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a texture:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 
             width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,  GL_FLOAT, 0);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_,                    
                       textureId, level);
```

to an FBO and then use this texture to draw a full-screen quad on the screen.

rendering to a texture and then using fullscreen quad:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

By using this `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` you will have max depth precision that hardware uses.
In the fragment shader (for the fullscreen quad) you can read from such texture and use it as a gray scale image.

here is another related question: [How to visualize a depth texture in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683011/how-to-visualize-a-depth-texture-in-opengl)

On the other hand if you want to have 32 bit buffer... maybe it is easier to use GL_R32F texture and calculate depth values in fragment shader. That way you will have better control over that process.

Comment: Hi Fen, thanks for your response. Can you please elaborate on "You can attach a texture: ... to an FBO and then use this texture to draw a full-screen quad on the screen." Thanks so much.